# take a join of two csv files over a common column in python

Tags: python, csv, join, pandas

I have two `csv` files which have following fields:

FILE 1 :

```
objectID,objectName,objecttype
```

FILE 2 :

```
objectID,objectprice,objecttotalprice
```

the data in these two files is separated by `,`. What I want is to take a join of these two files over `objectID`. The output should have joined data and the data of file 1 which did not matched with file 2. I tried this code but it is not giving correct output:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("file1.csv", names = ["objectID", "objectName", "objecttype"],header = 0).astype(basestring)

    b = pd.read_csv("file1.csv").astype(basestring)

    merged= a.merge(b, on='objectID',how='outer')

    merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

When I run this then in output I get data of `file1` (with empty value for fields of `file2`) followed by data of `file2` (with empty value for fields of `file1`).

What am I doing wrong here and how can I do the join correctly

**NOTE:** In `file1` the filed names are a bit different and hence I am renaming them when I am reading file1.csv above

Comment: Can you provide samples of the two files?

Comment: @Marcin Unfortunately due to some permission issues I cannot provide the samples. I would have provided if those issues were not there

Comment: Sometime different data types can clobber merging. If they are integers, try forcing each of the columns to be an integer:  `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].astype(int)`

Comment: I think you are taking the same csv file i.e. `file1.csv` in `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a left join, try

```
merged= a.merge(b, on='objectID', how='left')
```

It works like SQL (see the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging))

Comment: I did that too but the same output is coming as for outer

Comment: 'left' and 'outer' should give you different results, try it with some example data, e.g. `a = pd.DataFrame([{'x': 1, 'y': 1}, {'x': 2, 'y': 2])` and `b = pd.DataFrame([{'x': 1, 'z': 1}, {'x': 3, 'z': 3}])`